# How to add the Debug button to SSMS v18?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The `Debug` button is present on this version of SSMS:
[image]

But it is not present on version 18, preview 4:
[image]

I have tried in several ways to add the `Debug` button to my SSMS but not successful.

Is there a way to add the `Debug` button to SSMS v18?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Debugger is deprecated in SSMS18 as [@LowlyDBA said in his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221350/22336).

For those who look for an alternative, you can use [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)/Visual Studio to debug a query.

1. Connect to a SQL server (in Tools menu)
2. Open a new query (Server explorer, right click, new query)
3. Type in your query
4. Execute with Debugger

From the SQL menu

[image: SQL - Main Menu]

From the Drop down list next to the execute icon in the query window

[image: DropDown next to the Execute icon in the query window]

From the context menu in the query window

[image: Context menu in a query window]

Comment: Why do Microsoft removes standar functionality in tools? Do they hate us?

Comment: FYI, VS 2022 no longer works for debugging SPs.  Not sure what Microsoft broke with one of their VS updates, but we can't debug now.  When I open one of my Stored Procedures and then try "Execute with Debugger" I just get a spinning wheel and nothing happens ... in fact, I have to force VS 2022 to shutdown via TaskMgr.  Microsoft not only removed something that was working fine, then replaced it with something that doesn't work.

Comment: @RobAinscough perhaps it was a bug you encounter which has since been fixed but I've not experienced this myself. Debugging stored procedures is working in VS2022 version 17.4.4.

Comment: @cognophile you're correct ... my computer seemed to have been corrupted (domain accounts were all messed also) after I upgraded from Win10 install to Win11 install.  My solution was to wipe my PC and stay with Win10 (for now) ... debugging seems to be working now.

Answer (score 42):

This feature is [deprecated](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/04/24/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-0-released-for-general-availability/) in [SSMS 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-features) and thus no longer available.

Database diagrams were removed in SSMS 18 but have been re-added as of [version 18.1](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/06/11/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-1-is-now-generally-available/)