# Debugging TSQL in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

What techniques can I use to debug TSQL code now the debugger in SSMS 18 has been deprecated/removed?

Comment: Yes, looks the Debug has been deprecated!!!

Answer (score 2):

The way I am using might not the best, however, just to reassure you that this is possible and it has been working fine for me:

if you [really like the debug](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/221349/22336) least for now I am using both versions of `ssms`, the `17.9` and the `18` side by side as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

I use `sql server` from `2008 r2` up to `sql server 2017`.

Comment: Curious why use v18 at all? Without debugging I really have no use for it personally.

Comment: Anyone who thinks deprecation of debug was a bad idea please vote for it to be restored https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35881492-put-debugger-back-into-ssms-18